# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN' - sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Getting error near IN and here is my code

```
 DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime ='2018-04-01',
            @DateTo DateTime = '2018-05-31'

            WHILE @DateTo < @DateFrom 
            BEGIN
            set @DateFrom = DATEADD(D,1,@DateFrom)
             SET @DateFrom = DATENAME(DW, @DateFrom) IN ( 'tuesday','friday',null)
            END
```

I am getting error like

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The error makes sense - you cannot use `IN` in a `SET` statement.

Comment: i want to set all date to a variable.

Comment: This code looks more like sql server than mysql.

Comment: That is even more confusing. The logic of your loop is: While 2018-05-31 < 2018-04-01, add another day to the right hand side... In other words, the loop will never happen. If you replace `<` with `>`, all you are doing is comparing apples and oranges: `2018-05-31 > tuesday`...?

Comment: i have startdate and enddate and specific days. i want all the dates for those specific days in between these two dates and assign to one variable. please help me with writting complete query for the requirement.

Comment: What was wrong with the answer to your last question on this topic?

Comment: Variables other than table variables (which are not available in mysql) can only hold 1 value.

Comment: but we are using loop. so that value has to change though it holds only one value.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really mysql there are lots of errors 1) You don't declare @ variables 2) To allocate a value to a variable use a set statement or if it's a declared variable you can default a value 3) While statements syntax is incorrect it should be while something DO ... END WHILE 4) Every statement must be terminated 5) Multi code procedures must enclosed in a BEGIN..END block 5) This code must be in a stored program (procedure,trigger,function) 6) Delimiters possibly not set.

This at least syntaxs But I don't get what you are trying to do with the in statement.

```
drop procedure if exists p;

delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
set @DateFrom ='2018-04-01',
    @DateTo   = '2018-05-31';

   WHILE @DateTo < @DateFrom do 
      set @DateFrom = DATEADD(D,1,@DateFrom);
      SET @DateFrom = DATENAME(DW, @DateFrom) IN ( 'tuesday','friday',null);

   END while;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Even better if you would use local variables (declare) instead of user-defined variables. This way routines can safely call other routines wihout worrying the variable values might change.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime ='2018-04-01',
@DateTo DateTime = '2018-05-31'

WHILE @DateTo < @DateFrom 
BEGIN
set @DateFrom = DATEADD(D,1,@DateFrom)
    SET @DateFrom = case when DATENAME(DW, @DateFrom) IN ( 'tuesday','friday',null) then @DateFrom else null end

END
```